# Web archive file with non compiled java code

Tags: java, web-applications, business-objects, business-objects-sdk, war

I have .war file which has a directory structure as below:

```
Root
  |_META-INF
  |_THEME (CSS files)
  |_WEB-INF
        |_LIB 
        |_SRC (java source code)
```

As you can see above, there is NO classes folder. I searched throughout the root directory and i didnt find any .class files.

Does anyone know if the .class files would be generated during application server runtime? If so, how is this done.

To be more specific I'm encountering this problem with SAP Business Objects SDK - jsfplatform.war file. I'm trying to do some reverse engineering but unable to understand how actually is the process working.

Comment: Maybe in the /WEB-INF/lib/ directory as .jar file? If there is a /WEB-INF/web.xml look in there for class paths.

Comment: Look in the LIB folder for the .jars. Those might contain the .class files you're looking for.

Comment: thank you! it was indeed in the lib folder!